# NUnit3.ConsoleRunner with .NET Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

I'm trying to get NUnit3.ConsoleRunner version 3.70 NuGet package working in my .NET Core test assembly.  I've installed the NuGet package and have found that it's at this location:

> %userprofile%\.nuget\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner\3.7.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe

If I run the tool against my .NET Core 1.1 test assembly like so:

```
nunit3-console.exe MyTestAssembly.dll
```

I get the following errors (snippet from TestResults.xml):

```
<failure>
      <message><![CDATA[An exception occurred in the driver while loading tests.]]></message>
      <stack-trace><![CDATA[
Server stack trace: 
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadDriver(IFrameworkDriver driver, String testFile, TestPackage subPackage)
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadPackage()
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.EnsurePackageIsLoaded()
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Engine.ITestEngineRunner.Run(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)]]></stack-trace>
    </failure>
```

I also have the NUnit3TestAdapter NuGet package installed in that assembly (version 3.8.0-alpha1) and it's working well and all tests are passing.  What am I missing with running nunit3-console.exe against a .NET Core project?  I have it working in a .NET 4.5.2 app without issue.

Comment: Why don't you use `dotnet test` to run the tests?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to produce output for OpenCover + ReportGenerator in order to get unit test coverage working as I've done in the past.  It doesn't look like dotnet test is capable of producing output like NUnit.Console.

Comment: I had the same problem with TeamCity, but in the end I have changed the nunit runner to `dotnet test`. Have a look here [link](http://www.alteridem.net/2017/05/04/test-net-core-nunit-vs2017/)